# Is there any way to pass Task ID to the calling function?

Tags: c#, task

Is there any way to pass Task ID to the calling function?

Actually, I have a function `Run` defined in a separate file and it suppose to call a `callback` function on completion. I want this function to Task agnostics(i.e. don't want to use Task.CurrentId in it)

```
X.cs:
void Run(object userState)
{
    .
    .
    .
    callback(userState);
}
```

The purpose of the callback function is to do cleanup task in my case, i.e. free the reference of the Task I am storing in a task pool.

```
Y.cs
void LaunchTask()
{
    .
    .
    .
    Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Run(???)); //How to pass Task ID here as an argument yo Run?
    TaskPool[task.Id] = task;
}

void callback(object userState)
{
    .
    .
    .

    A a = (A)userState;
    var taskID = a.ID;
    TaskPool.Remove(taskID); //Free the reference of the task from the pool
}
```

Now my problem is that how I am going to pass task id to the `Run` function as a part of `userState`.

Answer (score 0):

it might be easier to put a continueWith on the original task  e.g.:

```
  public void LaunchTask()
    {
        Task<MyType> t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Run());
        t.ContinueWith( _ => CleanUpTask(t));
    }

    private void CleanUpTask(Task<MyType> task)
    {
        int id = task.Id;
        MyType t = task.Result;

        //cleanup
    }


    private MyType Run()
    {
        return new MyType {...};
    }
```

Comment: but in this way, I will not be able to get what function `Run` returns. Along with the userState, it also returns some other thinks too.

Comment: you can, you just need to use Task<T> - updated my initial response to reflect this